# .NET Dapper - Mapping computed properties

Tags: c#, .net, orm, dapper

I'm using Dapper for handling database connection in a .NET project. The automatic column mapping works well and I can also map columns to different property names in the model. However, how can I map computed properties? For example, my model is

```
class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsPremiumUser {get; set;}
}
```

And the table is

```
Id | Name | CreationDate | IsPremiumUser
```

Now, IsPremiumUser can be null in db but not in the model. I'd like it to be mapped by the following logic:

```
if (row.IsPremiumUser != null)
{
    model.IsPremiumUser = row.IsPremiumUser;
}
else
{
    model.IsPremiumUser = row.CreationDate < 1.1.2000;
}
```

In other words, its value depends on 2 columns. Also there are multiple cases where I'd like to set a boolean property based on if a certain relationship exists. How to handle these more complex mapping cases?

Comment: How this mapping should work when you will try to save an item back to database? if `IsPremiumUser` was null (when you read that), should it be updated and has a value?

Comment: Maybe you just need to and additional property that will be calculated but not mapped to db table?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Those computed values will not be saved back to db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SQL query which will check if `IsPremiumUser` field not null and return result of creation date check if user does not have this flag set:

```
var sql =
    @"SELECT 
        Id,
        Name,
        CASE
            WHEN IsPremiumUser IS NOT NULL
                THEN IsPremiumUser
                ELSE CAST(CASE WHEN CreationDate < '2000-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
        END AS IsPremiumUser
        FROM Users";
var users = conn.Query<User>(sql);
```

Other option will be using dynamic query with manual mapping results to user class:

```
var sql = @"SELECT Id, Name, CreationDate, IsPremiumUser FROM Users";
var millenium = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

var users = conn.Query(sql).Select(row => new User {
       Id = row.Id,
       Name = row.Name,
       IsPremiumUser = row.IsPremiumUser == null
           ? row.CreationDate < millenium
           : row.IsPremiumUser
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this approach, although it's not exactly what I had in mind. What if I have some more complex mapping logic that is not convenient to do on the db side?

Comment: @eko please refresh page :) Keep in mind that Dapper will return IsPremiumUser flag either as null or as boolean. It will not return nullable boolean

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make a factory and let it assemble the user:

```
var userRecords = _connection.Query<UserRecord>("select * from users");   
var users = UserFactory.Build(userRecords);
```

- UserRecord class is only used to query the data
- Factory will handle property mapping and dynamic properties

Pros: Keep SQL queries free of logic. Factory is more flexible over time.

Cons: More code